# Suggestions for Time Series Exercises

Tags: time-series, references

Do you know of a good set of exercises, preferably with solutions, that would help me learn Time Series by myself?

I was searching for solutions to the exercises of Shumway and Stoffer's «Time Series Analysis and its Applications», since it's the book I chose to follow, but I didn't find any...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Hamilton's _Time Series Analysis_ (1994) contains questions and _selected_ answers.

Comment: You might find questions/solutions in some popular econometrics textbooks if they contain chapters on time-series. For example, Gujarati's _Basic Econometrics_ (2008) covers time-series very briefly and there exists a solution manual. Stock and Watson's _Introduction to Econometrics_ (2010) would be similar; light theory and empirical applications.